# ng-sortable How to get the list id while item is reordered

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, reorderlist, ng-sortable

I am using `https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable` to reorder a list using drag and drop.

I am stuck at getting the list `id` when i move an item between two list. I want to know from which list the drag started and to which it was dropped.

```
<div id="list1" class="sortable-row" as-sortable="sortableOptions" 
    ng-model="itemsList.items1">
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList.items1" as-sortable-item>
        <div as-sortable-item-handle>{{item.Label}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the following `itemMoved()` method i want to get the list `id`

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    containment: '#sortable-container',
    itemMoved: function (event) {
        console.log("itemMoved()");
        console.dir(event);

        // Identify the list on which order changed

        // Get the last and new position


        // Update card position

    }
};
```

How do i identify the list on which drag started and on which drop was made.

> Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0FJt4?p=preview) for the same

Answer (score 4):

I debugged this little more. Found the id using the following:

```
console.log('From: ' + event.source.sortableScope.element[0].id);
console.log('To: ' + event.dest.sortableScope.element[0].id);
```

I hope this helps someone.

Updated the plnkr also for the same.

> http://plnkr.co/edit/o0FJt4?p=preview

Comment: now we can get item moved from and to directly, just use             console.log('From: ' + event.source.index);
console.log('To: ' + event.dest.index); . please update plunkr code for further usage. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Showing event.dest is indefined